# Tenacious/Unsung Hero: does "zero score" mean "zero score EVER"?

Tags: discussion, badges, zero-score-badges

(There are some other questions here about these badges, but none I could find answered this question.)

> **Tenacious**: Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total
>   **Unsung Hero**: Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

Are the answers considered for the Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges required to have *maintained* a zero score, or only have a zero score *at the time they were accepted* (or some time period thereafter)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, it means "Zero score at the time the job runs that awards the badges".

I guess this is how it works, sometimes timing is important:

Suppose you've got 30 Answers, 5 with 0 votes and 25 with upvotes. You don't get a Tenacious badge due to the "more than 5" rule.

Scenario 1:

- One of the 25 upvoted answers gets downvoted to zero score (at this point you qualify)
- The job that awards the badge runs: Badge awarded
- Your answer is upvoted again (or downvoted further), now you don't qualify anymore, but you keep the badge.

Scenario 2:

- One of the 25 upvoted answers gets downvoted to zero score (at this point you qualify)
- Your answer is upvoted again (or downvoted further), so you don't qualify anymore.
- The job that awards the badge runs. You don't get the badge awarded, even though you were elegible to get it somewhere inbetween.

Of course, the usual scenario would be to gain the badge for a newly accepted zero score answer instead of a downvoted one, but this kept the scenario of getting/not getting simpler I thought. The timing issue may or may not arise, this depends on how often the badge awarding jobs run. Since I've had badges that took a day to appear, this may come into play in some cases.

Comment: This makes sense, though is slightly disappointing. But is this actually how it works?

Comment: @jt I haven't got any of those two badges yet, but I think this is how it works. You've got to qualify for it _at the time the badge award job runs_, as with all other badges. The post history of up- or downvoting is not taken into account. _Electorate_ is another one that you may only qualify for at a certain point in time.

Answer (score 11):

No ... we do not take away these badges, if you happen to get votes on the question after you get the badge, you will retain the badge.

Comment: So if I write a new answer and it's accepted with no votes, then it gains votes, and if this happens several times... that will contribute towards the badge (even if I don't have it already)?

Comment: I don't think so... I think it just means that votes _once you've received the badge_ don't count.

Comment: @jtbandes ... yeah ... its not awarded for all questions that were accepted at 0 votes ... too many of them

Answer (score 6):

A couple of points that I've got to make on achieving these badges.

You need to get 6 zero score accepted answers and less than 30 accepted answers in total to achieve 'tenacious' - and then you need to maintain them at that level for 7-10 days for the badge to be awarded.  I didn't get the badge after 5 accepted zeros.

I currently have 10 zero score accepted answers (out of a total of 36 accepted answers), and won the tenth in June - so you definitely need 11 zero accepted answers for 'unsung hero'; and then I'd guess that you wait for a week or so for some batch sql agent job to run round the more rarely awarded badges.

**EDIT** Just got 'Unsung Hero' for the 11th accepted answer with zero upvotes (out of a total of 38 accepted answers).  Took just over a week for the award after I became eligible.